# Rename all files containing a specific string

Tags: linux, command-line, rename

I want to rename files of the type file_name (1).extension to file_name.extension. How can i use rename to delete the " (1)" string ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `find [path_to_dir] -type f -name "*file_extension*" -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; mv "$x" "${x}_renamed"' \;`

In my case, i find all .txt files in a folders, and rename it to filename_renamed.

```bash
find . -type f -name '*txt*' -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; mv "$x" "${x}_renamed"' \;
```